# Sawtooth CPU load pattern caused by memcpy(). A cpu-cache or memory-management issue?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, heap-memory, cpu-cache

As it may sound like an ffmpeg related issue, I believe it is not.

We have a system that processes live TV feeds by using ffmpeg's filters.

1. We capture frames from a video capture card and copy it into our own data structures.
2. We copy the frame info ffmpeg's native structures.
3. We run the filters.
4. We copy the resulting frame from ffmpeg's native structures back into our own structures.

A single frame uses 4.15 Mb dynamically allocated memory.
Frame buffers are allocated by using _aligned_malloc().
The server is a 2x Intel Xeon E5-2697v4 Windows Server 2016 box with 64Gb memory.

2 NUMA nodes. A process assigned to each node.

2 channels per process, a total of 4 channels per server, each at 25 fps.

A single default process heap is used for all memory allocations.
In addition to frame buffers, versatile dynamic memory allocations take place for multiple purposes.
Each process uses 2Gb of physical memory.

When we run the system, everything works fine. A flat CPU load is observed.
After a while (generally a couple of hours), we start seeing a sawtooth pattern in the CPU load:

[image: CPU Load Over Time]

When we investigate by using Intel's VTune Amplifier 2018, it shows that memcpy() in step2 consumes a lot of CPU time during those high-CPU periods.

Below is what we see from VTune 2018 Hot-Spot Analysis

```
**LOW CPU PERIOD (a total of 8,13 sec)**

SleepConditionVariableCS    14,167 sec CPU time
WaitForSingleObjectEx       14,080 sec CPU time
memcpy                       3,443 sec CPU time with the following decomposition:
  -- get_frame(step4)         -- 2,568
  -- put_frame(step2)         -- 0,740
  -- decklink_cb(step1)       -- 0,037

**HIGH CPU PERIOD (a total of 8,13 sec)**

memcpy                      16,812 sec CPU time with the following decomposition:
  -- put_frame(step2)         -- 10,429
  -- get_frame(step4)         --  3,692
  -- decklink_cb(step1)       --  2,236
SleepConditionVariableCS    14,765 sec CPU time
WaitForSingleObjectEx       13,928 sec CPU time
_aligned_free()              3,532 sec CPU time
```

Below is the graph of the time it takes to perform the memcpy() operation in step 2.
Y-axis is the time in milliseconds.

[image: Memcpy Time]

Below is the graph of total processing time for a single frame.
Y-axis is the time in milliseconds.
"0" readings are frame drops due to delay and should be neglected.

[image: Total Processing Time]

When the CPU gets higher and memcpy() starts to take longer, the handle count of our process decreases.

[image: Handle Count]

We logged the addresses that is returned from _aligned_malloc() in step2.
This is the buffer location in memory that we copy 4.15 Mb frame data to.

1. For low CPU periods, the addresses returned from _aligned_malloc() are very close to each other, ie. the difference between the addresses returned from two consecutive memory allocation operations tends to be small.
2. For high CPU periods, the addresses returned from _aligned_malloc() span a very large range.

[image: Memory Allocation Locality]

The sawtooth pattern we see in the total CPU load seems to be due to the memcpy() operation in step2.
For the high CPU periods, the buffer addresses that is returned from _aligned_malloc() seems to have bad locality when compared to the buffer addresses returned during low CPU periods.

We believe, the operating system starts doing something extra when we memcpy(). Some additional task during page faults? Some cleanup stuff? Is this a cache issue? Don't know.

Is there anybody that can comment on the reason and the solution to this situation?

Comment: The OS might not actually allocate the data on the heap until it is actually used, meaning that it doesn't necessarily get allocated during the `malloc` call, but later on when you first use it. This might be what you are seeing. If the access code is critical, then try to "dummy-access" the data directly after malloc, to move the allocation where you expect it to be.

Comment: The problem is the difference between the 'memcpy' times over a period of time. It takes longer to copy the memory in the sawtooth pattern(when CPU increases) I've provided with the images.

Comment: By the way, we are already accessing the 'malloced' memory directly after allocation just like you have suggested.

Comment: You have two processes, each pinned to a different NUMA node? Note that pinning processes or threads to nodes doesn't guarantee that memory allocations will only be satisfied from the node's memory. I suggest performing a [memory access analysis](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-memory-access-analysis).

Comment: Going to try that out and update with results.